# python modulo infinity

Tags: python, modulo, infinity

I have a code including modulo operation which involves infinity,
e.g. `a%numpy.inf`.

What i expected was to get zero, the code worked fine on my old computer.
However, I installed python, numpy now on my new computer and the operation gives `NaN`

Do you know how to get `a%numpy.inf` to be zero?

Comment: Why do you need this?  Mathematically, `a % infinity` should be equal to `a` (since the remainder of any number divided by infinity is going to be that number) or `NaN` (since division by infinity is undefined).  It may be better to change your code to deal with this new result.

Comment: @SamMussmann 
not right, the remainder of any number divided by infinity is NOT going to be that number, 2/infinity is an indertimination, so, is correct that `a%numpy.inf` be  `NaN`.

Comment: @levi: often we extend our number field to include +/-inf for convenience, and define the operations to give the most useful results.  There's nothing wrong with defining 2/inf to be 0 and 2 % inf to be 2.  Similar things are already done with floating point: try typing `print 1e500, 2.0/1e500, 2.0 % 1e500` at the Python console, for example.

Comment: @DSM is right, but I mean "Mathematically".

Comment: @levi: And I'm saying that even "mathematically", it's possible to do this consistently.  It's known as the [extended real number line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line), and R with +/- inf and the order topology form a two-point compactification of R.

Answer (score 1):

A good question, even though it got little attention. Mathematically, the commenters are right: `x mod inf` should yield `x` as can be seen [in this answer to my earlier question at Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1920338). So Python is correct. If you want to return zero instead, you will have to test for infinity with a simple `if`-statement prior to doing the calculation.